# How to update listview adapter after changing fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I have two fragments FragmentA and FragmentB. When I click on an item in FragmentB, it beging fragmentTransaction carrying some data.

FragmentA has a custom listview adapter that need to change when there is some data from FragmentB.

The problem is it didnot change.

here is the code in fragment A

```js
public class CardsFragment extends ListFragment {

   
    protected List<CardModel> list = new ArrayList<CardModel>();
    protected ArrayAdapter<CardModel> adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

       
        adapter = new CardAdapter(getListView().getContext(),
                list);


      

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
          
           LoadCards(args.getString("key"), args.getString("keyId"));

        }
        else{

            LoadAllCards();
        }

    }

    private void LoadAllCards() {
      
                        /**
                        
                        query the database code
                        
                        **/

                    list.add(...);

                    if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {

                        setListAdapter(adapter);

                    } else {
                       adapter.refill(list);

                    } 
    }


    private void LoadCards(String key, String keyId) {
      
                        /**
                        
                        query the database code
                        
                        **/

                    list.add(...);

                    if (getListView().getAdapter() != null) {

                        
                       adapter.refill(list);

                    } 
    }


/**

Refill function from adapter class

 public void refill(List<CardModel> cards){

        list.clear();
        list.addAll(cards);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }



**/


}
```

Comment: You've commented out refill(), but, that's the code that I'd have recommended.

Comment: Refill code exists in another class CardAdapter.java! I commented it in purpose of demonstration!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a very tricky problem that I faced. There are quite a few posts on stackoverflow on the same issue. I found a working example of this problem [here.](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/12/refresh-pageviewer-fragment-everytime.html)

Add a hash map to keep the tags of all the Fragments which have been instantiated. This way, from my FragmentActivity, I can check when the Fragment is the current fragment, in which case I call the onResume() method within the Fragment to refresh the content that I want to refresh.

Inside FragmentPagerAdapter

I define a hash map to store the Tags of the Fragments

```
mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Then I overrode the instantiateItem method to save the tag of the Fragment in the hashmap along with the position.

```
@Override  
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {  
Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);  
if (obj instanceof Fragment) {  
    // record the fragment tag here.  
    Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;  
    String tag = f.getTag();  
    mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);  
}  
return obj;  
}
```

Also, I created a method which will return tag of a previously created Fragment based on the position

```
public Fragment getFragment(int position) {  
    String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);  
    if (tag == null)  
        return null;  
    return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);  
}
```

Inside FragmentActivity, inside method on onPageSelected

```
Fragment fragment = ((FragmentPageAdapter)viewpager.getAdapter()).getFragment(arg0);  

if (arg0 ==1 && fragment != null)  
{  
    fragment.onResume();  
}
```

Inside onResume of your fragment, refresh the listView. This should do the trick.